YOLO fine-tuning RAM out of memory proble(python.exe takes over 8GB)
When I start fine-tuning yolo11n.pt (or any other version of yolo), the python.exe program will takes over 8GB, so I try everything to reduce the memory usage .
But anyway,the following is my model configuration ,I'm wonder is this normal or not? And does it influence the accuracy or is there a way I can improve it without causing OOM eeror?(my dataset only contains 2000 image)
 if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)  # Ensures proper process handling on Windows
    mp.freeze_support()  # Needed for Windows multiprocessing
    model = YOLO('yolo11n.pt')
    device=torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() 
    else 'cpu')
    results = model.train(
    data=data_yaml_path,
    epochs=150,              # Increased epochs
    batch=2,                # Reduced batch size
    imgsz=512,             # Reduced image size
    amp=True,
    # Stabilization parameters
    lr0=0.001,            # Lower learning rate
    lrf=0.001,  
    cache='disk',
    # Other parameters
    project='fall_detection_optimized',  # Save results in a new folder
    name='branch_first_phase',  
    device=device,
    optimizer='AdamW',
    workers=1,
    patience=25,
    weight_decay=0.0005,
    exist_ok=True,
    plots=True,
    save_period=50
)
# Save the best model
model.save('Fall_detection_optimized_best.pt')

So I lower everything and using cache to disk but it still takes 5GB, and I'm wonder does it impact the accuracy or how can I improve the accuracy

Please specify which actions are you taking to start the fine-tuning. Also please focus on one question at time (here should be OOM error, probably). As for accuracy, you will be able to assess it by yourself as soon as you finish your fine-tuning (and post another SO question if needed).

Got it! Sry I'm super new to this

set plots=False , show_labels=False in training parameters, your model will start training without any error.
There can be some issue with the images. we need to find the root cause.
